# Object screenoff in "onmouseover"

Tags: javascript

The code below shows a window when mouse is over a link. I wonder how to make this window appear on top of the word when it doesn't "fit" on the screen.

```
function showLayer(obj){
        var div = document.getElementById(obj).style;
        div.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: please describe your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your question, here is some jquery to help (also replaces `showLayer()`)

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", '#myElement', function () {
    $("#" + obj).toggle();
});

$(document).on("mouseout", '#myElement', function () {
    $("#" + obj).toggle();
});

$(document).on("mousemove", '#myElement', function (i) {
    $("#" + obj).offset(function () {
        return {left: i.pageX, top: i.pageY}
    });
});
```

im not sure how you get the value for `obj`, so you would have to edit to your specific needs.

Comment: `new Object();` should usually be `{}`. Additionally, you can make that function much nicer by just using `return {left: i.pageX, top: i.pageY}` (i don't think your answer is good/correct btw - why are you using delegates for example?)

Comment: fine no problem, thanks. i still think its a bit more understandable as originally written, but i edited t.

Comment: thats what we do here